# VLOOKUP with OR (Choices) in using different cell as a choice

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

How do I use `Vlookup` function with `OR`

For example if there is one value in the table either it is adj P/E or P/E or P/E ord adj.

I want to lookup that value.

[image]

Comment: What criteria decides which vlookup to use?  It would be best to show some sample data with expected outcomes.  Paste the sample as text in the original post.

Comment: @ScottCraner  it works thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways:

First if there is a common word in all the criteria that is unique, in your example `P/E` you can use wildcards:

```
=VLOOKUP("*" & "P/E" & "*",$H4:$L20,3,False)
```

Where `$H4:$L20` is your dataset and you want the third column in that dataset.

If not then you need to do the long way using IFERROR():

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$H4:$L20,3,False),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,$H4:$L20,3,False),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,$H4:$L20,3,False)IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,$H4:$L20,3,False),""))))
```

This will cycle through the criteria till it finds one that works.